# Strolling through the cornfields

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we really want to help or its just because of the reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32249/do-we-really-want-to-help-or-its-just-because-of-the-reputation-points)

And I don't care how many down votes I get for this, because these sites are useless to me. I always end up answering my own questions. It's almost a pointless waste of time. I'd do better to post it in a, what are those things called these days, "blog" (ghey). Then I'd remember it and other would benefit. It seems like these sites have turned into some kind of a competition. If that's what it's about, then that is really, hmmm, corny...

Oh I need to ask a question. Right. Here is an easy one to answer:

Are these sites about competing for rep and badges?

Comment: Huh? Wha? Oh...

Comment: not for you, i guess. troll.

Comment: @sims - Very high level programmers will find that SO is not a great resource for answering *their* questions.  If they are not interested in answering other people's questions, then honestly there's not much here for them.  I don't know if you fit into that category, but if you ask us to review your unanswered questions, we might be able to offer suggestions that will get your the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Trolling through the cornfields...

Comment: Indeed - call me supretroll! Gosh I feel bad now... :P

Answer (score 0):

You should be happy that you can find an answer to your questions.  Some questions are almost impossible to find answers to.

These sites are about gaining reps and badges for answering your questions.  Nobody gets much rep without answering some questions.

Comment: I am happy. I'm just amazed that so many questions go unanswered. I guess you didn't understand how corny I think reputation, in general, is. To be clear, I don't care about rep. I care about finding the answer. I also don't mind helping others find answers, but I don't really have much time for that - especially if they want to be spoonfed. I guess I'm too old fashioned... Off I go to some mailing lists...

Comment: @sims, I'm here, because I got tired of the long wait at mailing lists and forums.  I get my answers here really quick, with a few exceptions.  I have some unanswered questions also, but the vast majority have been answered quickly.

Comment: @sims FWIW, I don't think your questions remaining unanswered has anything to do with reputation - after all, answering questions is what gains reputation, isn't it? Why would people leave your questions unanswered out of greed for reputation points? I'd say they're simply very specific and very tough to answer, and there simply aren't that many people around who can answer them in the first place. Plus, you have asked a total of four questions to date. That isn't that many.